# Discount on shipping rate

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

I want to apply 15% discount on shipping rate that magento get from ups api.is it possible to do?

Comment: refer this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/316685/.
It is based on observer, but if you rewrite particular class it should work ok also. Note that inside this loop you should check that you are applying the discount only to the UPS rates

```
$rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
    ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
//Check that the carrier is UPS
if ($carrier->getCarrierCode() == 'ups') {
    foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
        //calculate 15% discount
        $rate->setPrice($price);
        $rate->save();
        print_r($rate->getPrice());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you tell me which file to modify?Its urgent

Comment: As mentioned you should create an event observer: http://www.meteorify.com/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/. Than in you config.xml subscribe for the <sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after>. Do not modify the core files(you will loose you changes on upgrade). Just create an event observer and follow the article http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/316685/.

Comment: I have override ups.php file in local folder. Is it ok?

Comment: I think it is better to use an observer as mentioned in  the article. It will save you some headaches in the future. Try to use an observer.

Comment: so for 15% discount ,$ rate-> setPrice ($ price*0.85) right?

Comment: Yes, this should work.